# rails collapse view in haml not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am following this thread to add to my haml view. [Bootstrap Collapse with Haml and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639651/bootstrap-collapse-with-haml-and-rails)
and I am having no success whatsoever. As far as my view, here is what I have:

```
- @vendors.each do |vendor|
 .panel-group{:id => "accordian"}
  .panel.panel-default
   .panel-heading
    %h4.panel-title
     %a.accordion-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-parent" => "#accordian", :href => "#{vendor.company_name}"}
     = vendor.company_name
    .panel-collapse.collapse.in{:id => "#{vendor.company_name}"}
```

The output I am getting is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nglb.png)

What else do I need to check?

Comment: Do not use single space as an indentation in haml, use at least two, otherwise it gets unreadable. You need to indent `=vendor.company_name` line one more level.

Comment: There might be a dependency in the files I am missing. Which files do I need to check? My view is working fine but the group is static; when I click the heading, the group does not collapse.